# Print new Prompt

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print in the document the new JavaScript object that the user has created by a button and a prompt. What I want is to print it under the last one created but it just overwrites the last object prompted.

```js
    var actividades = {


        "Colores" : [

          {"color": "Rojo"},
          {"color": "Verde"},
          {"color": "Azul" }

        ],

        "Deportes": [

          {"jugador":"messi", "edad": "30"},
          {"jugador":"lebron", "edad": "20"}

       ]
     }



  function crear(){
       var categoria = prompt("Seleccione un color");
       actividades.Colores.push({"color": categoria});
       JSON.stringify(categoria);           
       document.getElementById("colores").innerHTML +=  categoria + "<br>";
       console.log(actividades.Colores);
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="crear()">Crear Json</button>



  <div id="colores">

  </div>
  <div id="deportes">

  </div>
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(categoria);` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store output of `JSON.stringify(categoria);` in a variable

```
var colors = JSON.stringify(actividades.Colores);
document.getElementById("colores").innerHTML +=  colors + "<br>";
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` is a useless operation as `categoria` is already a string.

Comment: @Andreas I think he meant that he wants to print existing colors. He is using wrong variable. I am here using `actividades.Colores` in `JSON.stringify()`.